# create-react-app, service worker, and downloads

Tags: reactjs, flask, react-redux, service-worker, create-react-app

I've got two projects, let's say api and ui. The api is a python flask app, the ui is built with create-react-app. During development, I have express proxy the api, and everything's peachy. During production build, I use yarn build, take the static content, and serve it via the python api project. In the flask app, I'm service all api requests via "/api", and everything else from '/'.

Now, browser requests to /api/foo are bringing down index.html if serviceWorker is enabled. If I unregister service worker, then it simply gives an error stating that the url is wrong.

Is there some way to have service worker ignore all requests to /api/* ? Ideally, I'd like to not eject webpack config if possible.

Comment: See https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2398#issuecomment-334227447 for some more context about possible changes that would address this.

Comment: Did you try serving your react app from a different basename (like "website.com/app") instead of serving it from the root "/" ?